# Android set full screen from fragment

Tags: java, android

This is my question: I have an android app which allows users to go full screen for a better readability. The full screen fab toggle button is placed inside a fragment which actually contains the readings.

To make it dead simple:

- Main Activity contains Readings Fragment
- Readings Fragment contains a fab button to toggle full screen

To trigger the full screen I use this snippet:

```
this.fullScreenFab.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes();
    if (this.isFullScreen) {
        this.isFullScreen = false;
        ((AppCompatActivity) 
getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
    getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

} else {
    this.isFullScreen = true;
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

}
getActivity().getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
});
```

Now, it works well, except that the status bar and action bar spaces keep showing. The activity goes FS (even Android warn me of this) but the space  occupied by those two elements remain.

**Full screen disabled:**

[image]

**Full screen enabled:**

[image]

As you can see, the FS one has the top and bottom occupied, so the fragment does not go for a real full screen.

Fragment has the

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Send help please!
Thanks in advance.
Valerio

Comment: You can check android docs here https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: `getActivity(). getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` try this

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should try using this flag as it is designed to remove status bar and navigation.

```
getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

**NOTE:** You need to manually clear this while switching or closing fragment. Else this fullscreen will be applicable till the parent activity exists. To do so,

```
getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Also, you can use `FLAG_FULLSCREEN`. Using it will effectively set a transparent notification bar but the icons on the status bar will still show up.

Comment: Thank you, your snippet did the trick. With .clearFlags I can revert to the original settings.

Comment: I was glad to help!

Comment: when we add this line in code its just clear some settings from mobile to default like display goes off reset to factory reset

Comment: add them to onResume() and onStop() for better transition.

Comment: This just remove `status bar` layout but battery icon/time not hide. So use, `getActivity(). getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`  it will make black `status bar` and time&icons also hide.

Answer (score 14):

**Kotlin**

In `onViewCreated()` to make fragment fullscreen

```
requireActivity().window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

In `onDetach()` to clear fullscreen flag so it will not affect to other fragment which is open in Activity

```
requireActivity().window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

--x--x--x--x--x--x--x--x--x--

**Java**

In `onViewCreated()` to make fragment fullscreen

```
requireActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

In `onDetach()` to clear fullscreen flag so it will not affect to other fragment which is open in Activity

```
requireActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Answer (score 4):

System UI fullscreen flags are now deprecated, for API level 30 and above override `onWindowFocusChanged()` in your `MainActivity`

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
    if (hasFocus) hideSystemUI() else showSystemUI()
}

private fun hideSystemUI() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
        window.insetsController?.apply {
            hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() or WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
        }
    } else {
        // Enables regular immersive mode.
        // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
        // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    }
}
private fun showSystemUI() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
        window.insetsController?.apply {
            show(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() or WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
        }
    } else {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS and trying to transparent the status bar in fragments then you should clearFlags in onPause() instead in onDetach().

```
        override fun onPause() {
            super.onPause()
             
             (activity as MainActivity?)!!.window.clearFlags(WindowManager
                                 .LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)

             (activity as MainActivity?)!!.window.statusBarColor = Color.WHITE }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your splash fragment. It works for navigation also

in kotlin

```
 override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    requireActivity().window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

}

override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()

    requireActivity().window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This constant was deprecated in API level 30.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
```

Use **WindowInsetsController#hide(int)** with **Type#statusBars()** instead.
[See this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_FULLSCREEN)