# Set Fragment to FullScreen while using Navigation Component - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-fullscreen

I recently converted my app to Single Activity architecture and trying to set the one particular fragment to fullscreen. The standard fullscreen code for activity does not work for fragments

```
final int flags =
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
```

I found this [Android set full screen from fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446881/android-set-full-screen-from-fragment). But settings it to FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS causes the PagerSnapHelper in the fragment to jump around when switching between FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS and revoking it.

So my question is, is there any other way to set fragment to fullscreen without using FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS.

Comment: You don't ever need `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS`. What makes you think you need that?

Comment: So basically adding the flags
final int flags =
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    ....
Hides the status bar and navigation bar. But does not scale the fragment to fill the space. This is because I use fitsSystemWindows="true" in the activity top layout. Manipulating this programatically to false has no affect on the fragment.

Comment: So why are you using `fitsSystemWindows="true"` at the activity level when you actually only want it to apply to particular fragments?

Comment: I have a BottomNavigationView in the activity which should fit to the systemWindow. When going to the full screen fragment I hide the BottomNavigationView.

Comment: `fitsSystemWindows` on a `BottomNavigationView` does not affect whether fragments `fitsSystemWindows`.

Comment: I have the `fitsSystemWindows` in `activity_main`'s primary view. Actually, I found out that I needed the  `fitsSystemWindows` in activity because I set the theme for `MainActivity` to `<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>` I dont need that anymore. Removing that fixed the issue. I dont need the `fitsSystemWindows` in activity anymore. By default all the fragments are now fitting into the window and for fullscreen fragment, just updating the flags stretches it. Thanks for your help! Sorry If I wasted your time!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't ever need to use `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS`, nor should you apply `fitsSystemWindows="true"` globally at your activity layer - that is what would prevent your fragment from going full screen. Instead, only add `fitsSystemWindows` on the fragments / individual components that would otherwise overlap the status/system bars. This would ensure that your full screen fragment would be able to take up the full size and not be inset from the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the simplest solution that worked for me inside fragment :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    activity?.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
}
```

also clear the flag in onDestroy as below :

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    activity?.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
}
```