# Hide System bars and go full screen in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-windowmanager, layoutparams

I have been trying to make a fragment fullscreen, but almost every answer on the web has deprecated methods. Even the android official site has a deprecated method [Link](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/immersive).

I'm using kotlin and after following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446881/android-set-full-screen-from-fragment) answer, I have tried this in fragment.

```kotlin
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    requireActivity().window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
}

override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    requireActivity().window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
}
```

but the result that I got is this

[image]

You can clearly see navigation and status bars are still there.

Can you share the proper and latest way to get fullscreen in fragment?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the docs for [ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/ViewCompat#getWindowInsetsController(android.view.View)), you'll see that it's only deprecated because they want you to use [getInsetsController()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowCompat#getInsetsController(android.view.Window,android.view.View)) instead. Otherwise, the [sample code](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/ViewCompat#getWindowInsetsController(android.view.View)) works just fine.

Comment: Can you recheck the sample code link?

Comment: I use that code myself. what did you want me to check?

Comment: The link, I mean I didn't find the sample code there.

Comment: the sample code is in your OP: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/immersive

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the theme as follows

```xml
    <style name="AppTheme"parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For making a fragment full-screen.

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(requireActivity().window, requireActivity().window.decorView).apply { 
        
        // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
        hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        
        // Behavior of system bars 
        systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    }
}
```

Make sure to add this code in your fragment as well, it will show the system bars again.

```
override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(requireActivity().window, requireActivity().window.decorView)
        .show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
}
```

I don't know how WindowInsetsControllerCompat works but if anyone wants to hide system bars then this will help.